# Intellij PHP Import Highlighting

Tags: php, intellij-idea, configuration, highlighting

IntelliJ IDEA usually highlights classes that are not imported through the `use` keyword right before the class declaration. You can then `ctrl-enter` to insert the `use` import automatically.

It works on most of my projects, but not in all. Any idea where this can be set?

[image: Without the import]

[image: IntelliJ recognizes and suggests]

[image: After ctrl-enter, it is added]

I use Version 15.0.3, Build #UI-143.1821 and the latest PHP Plugin.

Comment: Can you edit the question mentioning exactly what version of IntelliJ Idea and version are you using? Are you using a PHP plugin for IntelliJ?

Comment: @alumarcu: see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vladimir Luchansky [wrote on the IntelliJ bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31018):

> Enable
>
> `File | Settings | Editor | Inspections > PHP | Undefined | Undefined
>   class`
>
> it will bring back "Import class" intention.

That solves it.

**How did it happen?**

Turns out, I turned this inspection off when trying to get rid of a "multiple implementations exist" message (cannot avoid)

[image]

...and then:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have PhpStorm but I assume the settings look the same in Intelij IDEA with PHP plugin. That is, you should be able to find it under Settings > Editor > General > AutoImport. (Just search for "auto-import")

[image: Importing in Intellij/PHPStorm]

But **it also may be that the location of that certain file cannot be found by PhpStorm/IntelliJ and you need to add it to your include path**.